# There is no method addNotificationBlock in Realm. Where is it?

Tags: swift, notifications, realm

I'm trying to use `.addNotificationBlock` method in Swift Realm. I have other methods but not actually this one (look at the image). Why?

```
let realm = RealmService.shared.realm
racks = realm.objects(Rack.self)

notificationToken = realm.??? { (notification, realm) in
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

[image]

Comment: Check this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57039131/10379874)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 3.0.0 Release notes (2017-10-16)
>
> Breaking Changes
>
> Old API    New API
>
> NotificationToken.stop()   NotificationToken.invalidate()
>
> -[RLMNotificationToken stop]   -[RLMNotificationToken invalidate]
>
> **RealmCollection.addNotificationBlock(*:)***   **RealmCollection.observe(:)**

Try `observe`?

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5**

```
//Refresh the tableView in Real time returning a notification token
        notificationToken = realm.observe { (notification, realm) in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        notificationToken.invalidate() // instead of stop()
```